# Access Violation in Telerik WinForms on Application Close

Tags: winforms, telerik, access-violation

I'm getting this error about 2 out of 3 times when closing my application running on XP SP3. I have not been able to repro on Win 7. Any insight on what may cause such an error would be appreciated.

It is not the same control every time, but it is always one of the Telerik controls. I'm using their latest 2011 Q1 release.

Framework Version: v4.0.30319
 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
 Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
 Stack:
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridViewElement.DisposeManagedResources()
    at Telerik.WinControls.DisposableObject.PerformDispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.PerformDispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.DisposableObject.Dispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.DisposeChildren()
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.PerformDispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.DisposableObject.Dispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.ComponentThemableElementTree.Dispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.Dispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridView.Dispose(Boolean)
    at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadHostItem.DisposeManagedResources()
    at Telerik.WinControls.DisposableObject.PerformDispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.PerformDispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.DisposableObject.Dispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.DisposeChildren()
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.PerformDispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.DisposableObject.Dispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.DisposeChildren()
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.PerformDispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.DisposableObject.Dispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.ComponentThemableElementTree.Dispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.Dispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadPopupControlBase.Dispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.MultiColumnComboPopupForm.Dispose(Boolean)
    at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.PopupEditorBaseElement.DisposePopupFormCore(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.PopupEditorBaseElement.DisposeManagedResources()
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadMultiColumnComboBoxElement.DisposeManagedResources()
    at Telerik.WinControls.DisposableObject.PerformDispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.PerformDispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.DisposableObject.Dispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.DisposeChildren()
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadElement.PerformDispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.DisposableObject.Dispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.ComponentThemableElementTree.Dispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.Dispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadMultiColumnComboBox.Dispose(Boolean)
    at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadPageViewPage.Dispose(Boolean)
    at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean)
    at Telerik.WinControls.RadControl.Dispose(Boolean)
    at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose(Boolean)
    at Cps.DocReview.FormMain.Dispose(Boolean)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmClose(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
    at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.DefWndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
    at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmSysCommand(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
    at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
    at Cps.DocReview.Program.Main()